# Remove highlight on press in tablayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tablayout

[image]

How to disable this highlight on pressing the tab. I have been searching for half an hour and couldn't figure it out. I am using tablayout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just set the background color to transparent or to the background color of the tablayout. Add the following code to the parent layout.

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And add the following to tablayout.

```
app:tabBackground="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

This will solve your problem. Tested in Android M.

Comment: In my xml I have Toolbar and TabLayout and ViewPager. Toolbar and Tablayout have their backgrounds set but it still highlights on press. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: add the following code to parent layout
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
and the following code to the tablayout
app:tabBackground="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

Tested with the android version M and it is working.

Comment: app:tabBackground saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Add the below line to your XML:

```
app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: This should be added to the excepted answer. I was only able to remove all background highlights after also making the ripple transparent. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to disable color when unselected tab is selected,i.e: android:state_focused="true", then this is the solution. Thank you sir for this solution!

Comment: it's the wrong answer.
The correct answer is not to hardcode this attribute