# How to disable click effect on TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How to disable this click effect?

[image]

I tried to add these to Activity's theme but not working

```
<item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="tabBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

I also tried to use the theme in TabLayout directly but the app will crash

And also tried `android:stateListAnimator`, but still not working

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null">
```

Comment: did you try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866608/2919483

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change the tab background as transparent `app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"`, like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

It does work, I have verified.

Comment: Also, what is the name of this effect?

Comment: It's called ripple effect

Comment: I first tried the below answer and during build process `app:tabRippleColor` not found error occurred. So then I switched to  this answer and worked like charm.

Answer (score 45):

Use `app:tabRippleColor="@null"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:tabStripEnabled="true"
        app:tabBackground="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null" />
```

This works for me.

Comment: this is the better answer

Answer (score 10):

Do this:

```
app:tabRippleColor="@null"
```

This basically disables the ripple background resource.

Comment: A little explanation really improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
tabLayout.setTabRippleColorResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in tablayout xml:
app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"